# Use apache to block a url with specific query string

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, querystring

I have this url:

```
mysite.com?var=var&var2=var2&var3=var3
```

I would like to block this specific url but not in any way affect other query strings on the same base url.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You can use ModRewite to check for query strings and redirect or block a page. Using your example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=var
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=12/12/12
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var2=word\+word
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

(There's an implicit AND between the RewriteCond statements)

This would block ([F]) all pages (.*) that had all three of those querystring parameters and values.

UPDATED to use more specific examples by the OP

Comment: Actually, that doesn't appear to work - any other ideas?

Comment: It worked in my local Apache install. Is RewriteEngine On? What happens when you hit the URL above?

Comment: @rix Keep in mind that there may be characters in your string that need to be escaped with a `\` when used in a regex.  If this doesn't work, try setting a `RewriteLog` and turn `RewriteLogLevel` to 9, and let us know what that gives you.

Comment: Ah right, I have / in the var ie a date=12/12/12 and other than that just + for spaces.  ie var=word+word - does the + and the / need to be escaped?

Comment: The `+` needs to be escaped: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=word\+word`